# SSRS Display SQL query in proper format

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

I have a requirement to display length sql queries (10-15 line) on SSRS report UI. I have a challenge in reading them. Is there a way, where I can apply SQL formatting option?

Answer (score 0):

I think the following experision will be solved your issue

```
=DataSets!DataSetName.CommandText
```

Also you can see the [What DataSet Query Text Is Executed?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/robertbruckner/2008/10/25/what-dataset-query-text-is-executed/)

Comment: but how commandtext will format the query value. I have a report, which display "select" query as a string. I want to format that value.

Comment: Do you want to fortmat the SQL query text?

Comment: Yes I am displaying query as a result output of recordset. Query having 15-20 lines. It is not looking good. Is there a way I can format?